# I set an environment variable in /etc/environment, but it's not in printenv using bash.exe with Windows cmd. Why?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, environment

I'm using WSL and I'm quite new on Linux. I have set an environment variable in `/etc/environment` called TESTVAR. This variable is required for some projects and it's working just fine when I'm running Bash directly.

But if I'm running a Linux command using the Windows cmd like: `bash.exe -c "printenv"`, the variable doesn't exist. So I can't run my commands using cmd otherwise I'll get many errors because the variable contains an important path.

What do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have other variables in /etc/environment, and do they show up in the `printenv` output?

Comment: No, except the PATH maybe but not more. But when i'm doing printenv using the cmd Windows i have some variable like: TERM,NAME,HOME and some more, but none of them have been added by me.

Answer (score 5):

There are several methods for bash on Windows

See https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/24

Basically you add them to ~/.bashrc

If that is not working post your .bashrc

I don't know why /etc/environment is not working.

Comment: my vars are in ~/.bashrc and have same problem

Answer (score 1):

Old post but if anyone stumbles here from google...

As of Windows version 17134, adding the `-i` flag to the `bash` command will run the shell command as "interactive" which will invoke the full linux environment including any login dot files that are set up (.bashrc, .bash_aliases, etc.) which might hold environmental or variable definitions.

For the original question, from Windows cmd this should have the desired effect:
`bash -ic printenv`

See also: `bash -ic 'man bash'`

Answer (score 0):

## WSL Bash works the same as Ubuntu Bash

**EDIT:** Original answer below for historical comments. Panther's answer is best. Your `~/.bashrc` file which is processed each time the terminal is opened. In it place the command:

```
MY_VARIABLE="some text"
```

Then you can use `echo $MY_VARIABLE` to see it's setting.

---

I opened a new Bash Terminal Window in WSL which works the same way in Ubuntu 16.04 except the splash screen is subtlety different:

[image]

As you can see once you set an environment variable it can be recalled normally.

Perhaps your bigger problem is with your command:

```
bash.exe -c "printenv"
```

On one of my Windows 10 desktop shortcuts I use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "cd && DISPLAY=0:0 /mnt/e/bin/lock-screen-timer"
```

Perhaps you are missing something there???

---

## Reply to comments

In response to your comments to someone else, my system, like yours, reveals:

```
rick@alien:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ echo $TERM,$NAME,$HOME
xterm-256color,alien,/home/rick
```

So you should not be unduly concerned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you want to use your Linux (Ubuntu) environment variables, you have to run the following command:

```
bash --login -c "printenv"
```

You can see some discussion relating to the issue in this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2634)

Comment: So "yourlinuxcommand" would be `/etc/environment`? I'm not so sure this would be the best place. I think Pather's answer is better...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `/etc/environment` is not command but it is a system-wide configuration file! You can set your user variables in 3 files: `/etc/environment`, .profile or .bashrc  ... to use them, you have to run the command  in my answer! So the command must be, for example, like: `bash --login -c "printenv"`

Comment: I see your answer has changed. Disregard my first comment.